# Find the first four terms in the binomial series expansion

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How do you find the first four series of $f(x) = (x + 2)(x+1)^\frac{1}{3}$?

If it were just $(x+1)^\frac{1}{3}$, I know how to solve it via the binomial theorem, but are you supposed to multiply the $(x+2)$ in after?

Comment: Yes. Just multiply the power series by $x+2$.